# R4 chip on new Nintendo 3DS XL will brick it or safe?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I bought one a while back (see pic below) for my original DS and now I've got a new Nintendo 3DS XL on which I'd like to play the games already on there.  I called Nintendo of America and Nintendo Japan and they said, "It is not illegal to possess it but illegal to sell the R4" when I called to offer to give them my R4 as I felt guilty.
Anyways, since the rules allow me to have it, I'd like to know if I can use the chip on my new machine without bricking it.  Online forums seem to be conflicting in their answers so I thought I'd ask here.

[image: R4 chip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!  I read this: [quora link](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-my-old-r4-card-in-the-new-Nintendo-3DSs-DS-slot)

Then I tried it but it told me my firmware was outdated and to reset the date so I went into settings on my machine, set the date back to the year 2000 (can't go any earlier) and bingo!  No problems whatsoever, mind you my R4 if you look at the photo carefully does say 3DS on it.

To clarify, my machine is not bricked and to play a different game I just press the home button, go back to menu and through the process of loading cartridge and choosing a different game.

Answer (score 0):

This R4 chip is with Timebomb, so it's not a good R4, and if you set up the flashcard on your console normally, it won't cause any issue. [R4 card](https://www.nx-card.com/17-play-ds-games) won't brick your 3DS or other consoles, so don't worry.